# Using LINQ to get DataGridView row index where first column has specific value

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'd like to get the index of a DataGridViewRow, where the value of its first column matches.

My code so far:

```
string SearchForThis = "test";

int index = from r in dgv.Rows
            where r.Cells[0].Value == SearchForThis
            select r.Index;
```

The compiler error:

Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'r'.

Comment: Try replacing `dgv.Rows` with `dgv.Rows.Array`. Does that work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DataGridViewRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, that is why you can't use LINQ, use [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method.

```
int index = (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value == SearchForThis)
                    .Select(r => r.Index)).First();
```

Or with Query Syntax:

```
int index = (from r in dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            where r.Cells[0].Value == SearchForThis
            select r.Index).First();
```

You will need to get a single result back from the collection, that is why I have used `First`, but remember if there are no items matching the criteria, it will **throw an exception.** To overcome that see the solution at the end of answer.

See: [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

> The `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)` method enables the standard query
>   operators to be invoked on non-generic collections by supplying the
>   necessary type information. For example, `ArrayList` does not
>   implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but by calling
>   `Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)` on the `ArrayList` object, the standard
>   query operators can then be used to query the sequence.

*(You can also use `Enumerable.OfType` method, that will ignore all those which are not `DataGridViewRow`, but with `DataGridView`, Cast is fine as well)*

You can also use `FirstOrDefault` to get the row first and then get the index like:

```
int index = 0;
var item = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value == (object)1);
if (item != null)
    index = item.Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally like these forms, (although the fact that the Rows are not a proper collection is syntactically annoying):

```
 var hit = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().First(row => row.Cells["MyColumnName"].Value.Equals(MyIndexValue));

 var hit = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(row => row.Cells["MyColumnName"].Value.Equals(MyIndexValue));
```

If you only want the first one, it gets simpler:

```
 var hit = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().First(row => row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(MyIndexValue));
```