# How to use LINQ to get DataGridView cell Value

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Is there a possibility to use a LINQ query to receive the Value of the highlighted Cells? In the figure below, i can only count the highlighted cells in the DatGridView and pass the count number in a listBox.

```
var foundColor = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(row => new 
{  
  Count = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Count(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow),
  Name = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Where(x => x.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
}).ToList();

foundColor.ForEach(s => listBox3.Items.Add($"{s.Count},{s.Name}"));
```

[image: DataGridView Sample]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LINQ to get DataGridView row index where first column has specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083959/using-linq-to-get-datagridview-row-index-where-first-column-has-specific-value)

Comment: Do you have logic which change cell back colors? Maybe you can re-use this logic to calculate values?

Comment: I dont really know, but thank you very much for your help, Fabio.

Comment: This coud have been another interesting approach. Thank you very much, Anas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SelectMany to create a flat list of your cells.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
```

Now you have a IEnumerable, you can use Count, or Where, or Select the Value of the cell.

Count and Select you cannot do in the same iteration. That would be two queries.

But putting you result in an array or List and taking the length of that list, would be the better idea, in matter of performance.

```
var list =     dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>())
    .Where(x => x.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
    .Select(cell => cell.Value)
    .ToList();
int count = list.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts, Holger. This is an interesting approach, but i can only count the highlighted cells. With your code i can’t  pass the highlighted cell value into a listbox.  How to do that?

Comment: @Marcel16 Use `list`, it contains the values you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice,Sнаđошƒаӽ!